# Bayes - Integral to Gamma Function

Tags: bayesian, expected-value, gamma-distribution

When trying to understand my professors notes, I came upon this piece and don’t understand the step he took.

$\frac{(\sum x_i+2)^{n+1}}{\Gamma (n+1)} \int_0^\infty\theta^{n+1} e^{-\theta \sum x_i+2}\text{d}\theta$

To

$\frac{(\sum x_i+2)^{n+1}}{\Gamma (n+1)}  \frac{\Gamma (n+2)}{(\sum x_i+2)^{n+1}} $

Comment: Google Gamma distribution and Gamma function.

Comment: Thanks, I got the $\Gamma (\Theta) = \Theta^{n+1}*e^{-\Theta} $. But why do we have divided by the term above?

Comment: That's not what the Gamma function is: in your comment you have written down part of the *density* for a Gamma$(n+2)$ distribution.

Comment: Hint: try a change of scale in the original integral.